# How to add External data source into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, odbc, filemaker

I have two database. One is a **FileMaker** database and the other one is **mysql**. I want to use this database in mysql. I created ODBC data base connection so that I can sync both database e.g when I make changes in mysql database then FileMaker database should also be updated. Is this thing possible in mysql? If not then in which open source database this thing is supported?

Comment: An ODBC data source to a MySQL database? Or from a MySQL instance to something else? Edit more details into the question please. This will avoid your question being put on hold for being unclear.

Comment: @paul : I edited this question please have look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you're asking (i.e.: replicate content from MySQL to FileMaker). FileMaker doesn't have (as of current version) any way to automatically replicate data from external sources.

Instead of that, you can do something different with equivalent result: **access your MySQL data directly from FileMaker**. This means FileMaker never has a copy of the data. You just have one data source (MySQL), and have FileMaker `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` or `UPDATE` that MySQL table directly.

You can do that for as many *tables* on as many *MySQL databases* as necessary.

You do this by using in FileMaker an "external data source". Check [Connecting to data sources](https://www.filemaker.com/help/15/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help/connecting-to-data-sources.html) from FileMaker.

---

NOTE: This has been available in FileMaker since (as far as I can remember) version 12. FileMaker allows also connections to other RDBMS such as Microsoft SQL server and Oracle. Newer versions of FileMaker allows also external sources to be PostgreSQL and others [(See here)](https://www.filemaker.com/support/technologies/sql.html)